# Hide a div on embed tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an embed tag on a site with an external source.
I'd like to hide a div on the external source that I'd like to hide.

The embed code is this:

```
<embed src="https://www.site.com" width='100%' height='1000px'/>
```

And the div has a class and inline style

```
<div class="button" style="display:block !important;">
```

Is it possible to hide with javascript or CSS?
I know that I can't do it with an iframe for security issues, is it the same with embed tag?

Or do I have other ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, define ID for both control as:

```
     <embed id="embedID" src="https://www.site.com" width='100%' height='1000px'/>
     <div id="divID" class="button" style="display:block !important;">
```

After that write below code:

```
     $("#embedID #divID").remove();
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you that the external site is in a different domain from mine. Could this work even with the DIV class?

Answer (score 0):

Give the button an ID. For example: button1

```
<div class="button1" style="display:block !important;">

$("#button1").remove();
```

or

```
$("#button1").hide();
```

if you want to define multiple ID's at once, you can use:

```
$("#button1 #button2").remove();
```

or

```
$("#button1 #button2").hide();
```

Both should work!

For external links like you mentioned in the comments:

Using JQuery you should be able to exactly that with the load-function. Here is a small example to get a container with id "container" on a page called Test.html:

```
$('#contentDiv').load('/Test.hmtl #container');
```

You can visit the JQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more info

Comment: I forgot to tell you that the external site is in a different domain from mine, so I can't give an ID to the DIV

Comment: But the mentioned DIV has not an ID and I can't give that because it's an external site...

Comment: Then I don't think it is possible, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].style.visibility='hidden';
```

This may help you.

Comment: Tried but didn't work. 
I forgot to tell you that the external site is in a different domain from mine.